# Clip an entire SVG perfectly inside a container div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG element inside a container like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg class="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2484.44 1971.36">
  <defs>
  <style>
    .cls-1 {
      fill: none;
    }

    .cls-2 {
      clip-path: url(#clip-path);
    }

    .orange {
      fill: url(#radial-gradient);
      transform: translate(0, -100vh);
      fill: orange;
    }
  </style>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect class="cls-1" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
     <g class="cls-2">
      <circle cx="15.05" cy="1439.67" r="15.05" />
      <circle class="orange" cx="1498.76" cy="985.68" r="985.68" />
     </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And my css like so:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.svg {
  background: pink;
}
```

I would like to be able to translate my elements around in an animation without having them extend past the container box. More specifically, I'm animating the circles to "drop" into the box from offscreen. I have created a svg `clipPath` but I cannot get the `clipPath` to match the container div.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3faz3vx6/4/) is a Fiddle that describes my problem. In this case, I need the pink area to match the green.

Is this possible to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `viewBox` in your SVG, then you are going to need to continuously update it so it stays in sync with the container `<div>` width and height.  Otherwise it will always be scaled differently.  You'll need to use javascript and watch for onresize events.

Alternatively, remove the `viewBox` and live with the fact that your SVG scale will always be 1:1.

https://jsfiddle.net/3faz3vx6/5/

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I ended up just removing the viewBox as you suggested and fiddling around with the transform scale with media queries.